# Adding new column to R dataframe that is the result of any() on another column

Tags: r, logical-operators, mutate

I am trying to use mutate to create a new column based on the presence of any TRUE in a column that contains a vector of TRUE/FALSE.

Given the sample code I was expecting to see the 'Allow" column to contain (FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE). What I get is all TRUE.

```
library(dplyr)

GroupName <- c("Mayfair", "Chronos", "Orion", "Milkhouse", "Saddle", "Westeros")
Region <- c("A12", "S19", "T12", "T11", "S16", "B2")
GroupAssociation <- data.frame(GroupName, Region)

regID <- c("S", "T1")
groupMap <- GroupAssociation
groupMap$allowed <- lapply(groupMap$Region, stringr::str_starts, regID)
groupMap <- mutate(groupMap, Allow = any(unlist(groupMap$allowed) == TRUE))
```

Answer (score 1):

We could loop over the `list` with `sapply` and apply `any` instead of `unlist`ing the whole list

```
groupMap$Allow <- sapply(groupMap$allowed, any)
```

---

Or with `tidyverse`, it can be `map_lgl`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
groupMap %>%
   mutate(Allow = map_lgl(allowed, any))
```

---

Or in newer versions of `purrr`, use `list_c` after `map`ping

```
groupMap %>% 
   mutate(Allow = map(allowed, any) %>%
   list_c(.))
```

Comment: Thanks.  I had tried the map_lgl but must have coded it wrong. This works fine.

Answer (score 0):

To follow your syntax, you need `rowwise()` before `mutate`. Within the `mutate` command, you don't need to use the `$` syntax to refer to column, just the column name is enough. Also, `any(... == TRUE)` is redundant because `any` itself already tests for any TRUE values.

```r
library(dplyr)

groupMap %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(Allow = any(unlist(allowed)))
```

Comment: Appreciate the suggestion of using rowwise.  I always forget about that :)